# Encoding memory operands using the RSP register in x64 - SIB byte needed?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, machine-code, addressing-mode, instruction-encoding

I'm trying to understand how to encode reads on the RSP register in x86-64.

For example, I have some code like this:

```
.section __TEXT,__text
.global _main

_main:
  push %rsp
  push (%rsp)
  mov %rsp, %rax
  mov (%rsp), %rax
```

When I assemble and dump the output, it looks like this:

```
$ as -o thing.o thing.s && objdump -d thing.o
                                                      
thing.o:        file format mach-o 64-bit x86-64      
                                                      
                                                      
Disassembly of section __TEXT,__text:                 
                                                      
0000000000000000 <add2>:                              
       0: 54                            pushq   %rsp  
       1: ff 34 24                      pushq   (%rsp)
       4: 48 89 e0                      movq    %rsp, %rax
       7: 48 8b 04 24                   movq    (%rsp), %rax
```

`push (%rsp)` becomes `ff 34 24`.  From what I understand, 0xFF is the opcode for PUSH,  and 0x34 is Mod/RM encoding.  I don't understand where 0x24 is coming from though.  Is this the SIB byte?  How is this instruction encoded?  I can't seem to follow the Intel manual well enough to figure out where this byte comes from.  I see the same byte in `mov (%rsp), %rax`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600668/what-meaning-if-any-does-the-mod-r-m-byte-carry-for-the-unconditional-jump-ins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To encode `push (%rsp)` look up the `push` instruction in the instruction set reference. You will see it is listed as `FF /6`. Then turn to chapter *3.1 INTERPRETING THE INSTRUCTION REFERENCE PAGES*, in particular, section *3.1.1.1 Opcode Column in the Instruction Summary Table* where you will see:

> /digit A digit between 0 and 7 indicates that the ModR/M byte of the
> instruction uses only the r/m (register or memory) operand. The reg
> field contains the digit that provides an extension to the
> instruction's opcode.

To encode `(%rsp)` (or `[rsp]` in intel syntax) you will need a SIB byte. Consult *Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte*. While it says 32 bit, it mostly applies to 64 bit as well with the logical extensions. Since the instruction has `/6` look at the penultimate column, and the row that says `[--][--]` with the footnote telling you this is the one that allows you to specify a SIB byte. The value in this cell is `34` (hex) so that's where that comes from. As for the SIB byte itself, consult the next *Table 2-3. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the SIB Byte*. You want the column with the heading `ESP` (the 32 bit equivalent to `RSP`) and the row `none` which gives you the `24`.

Comment: Got it.  Thank you so much for such a clear explanation!

Comment: @AaronPatterson: For the other special cases ("escape codes") of ModRM/SIB encoding, see [rbp not allowed as SIB base?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52522544)